# Target last active li

Tags: css

Anyone suggest me how to add CSS in li last active class

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean, do you want to add some style on your last li element which has active class? or do you want add active class on your last li element?

Comment: Ideally, `.active:last-of-type` would work here. But, un-intuitively, it does not.

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar yes I want to add CSS in last active class in the li

Comment: Per the duplicate answer, JavaScript is the only option here with your current markup and classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only tow class active you can use `.active ~ .active { ... }`
Else with JS try something like that :

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
x[x.length - 1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="active"></li>
<li class="active"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```